# How to run a function if unobtrusive have validated in asp.net 4.5

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I working on visual studio 2012 webforms and i have a issue with unobtrusive validation . That technique is very great for webforms developers! I have one validator and i dont know **how to run a jquery function if unobtrusive validation is validated**. It work fine but server will be submit if unobtrusive was validated. Now i wanna run a jquery function if unobtrusive was validated. Below is my markup! Hope you take a look and help me solve this issue!

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>    

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="txt1" Display="Dynamic" Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Validation" />
```

Hope receive some helps! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my MVC project, I use `validate()` function to trigger the validation. Followed by `valid()` function to check whether the form passed the validation.

```
  $("#yourForm").validate();
  if ($("#yourForm").valid()){
    //run code if the form passed the validation
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for help me but it doesn't work because webforms don't use external .js like validate and unobtrusive plugin like MVC! For that webforms automatically generate unobtrusive validation when i use Validator. Needn't call validate() function of jquery. Anyway i really really thanks for helping! Anybody help me please!